# Import multiple PostGIS layers in QGIS map canvas via QTask QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, postgis, database

The vertex tool in red and the geometry displayed by the layer in yellow are not in sync

[image]

```
from time import sleep
from qgis.PyQt.QtSql import QSqlQuery, QSqlDatabase
serverName = 'hostname'
database = 'dbname'
port = 'port'
usr = 'username'
pw = 'password'
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(serverName, port, database, usr, pw)

def stopped(task):
    pass
def completed(exception, result=None):
    pass
def run(task, wait_time):
    # main code    
    wait_time = wait_time / 100

    Layers= ['120_pipes']

    for i, lyr in enumerate(Layers):
        task.setProgress(i)
        sleep(wait_time)
        uri.setDataSource('120', lyr, "wkb_geometry")
        vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), lyr, "postgres")
        if vlayer.isValid():
            g = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().insertGroup(0, '120')
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer, False)
            g.insertChildNode(0, QgsLayerTreeLayer(vlayer))

        if task.isCanceled():
            stopped(task)
            return None

task = QgsTask.fromFunction(u'Task', run,
                            on_finished=completed, wait_time=50)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is that after you move a vertex with the Vertex Tool, the tool "remembers" where the vertices used to be, and can't detect them at their new location. Can you confirm that I correctly understand the problem?

Comment: @csk, yes this is the problem!